# loading on navigating between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new in RN. When I want to navigate between screens I create this function:

```
    displayScreen2 = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("screen2")
    }
```

and I call it in `onPress={this.displayScreen2}`
with TouchableOpacity or any Touchable when the user clicks he has to wait 1 second or 2 before displaying the screen. So what I want is to change the Touchable icon to an loader.
It's simple if I use a conditional rendering but I don't know how to do it now, when I have to change my state? Any suggestions?

this is my approach:

```
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={Styles.topButton}
            onPress= {() => {
              this.setState({loading: 'load'},
                () => {
                  displayScoreListView()
                  // this.setState({loading: 'icone'})
                }
              )
              }}
          >

<Text style={Styles.scoreListButtonTextRed}>{this.state.loading}</Text>
```

that not work, tha state change but visualy not because if I return to the first screen I have 'load' in the text component

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom component wrapping whatever `Touchable` you prefer, I've used this technique in my production apps before. The button has it's own state which allows you to automatically display a loading indicator when necessary.

```js
export class ButtonWorker extends Component {

    state = {
        working: false
    }

    onButtonPress = () => {
        this.setState(
            { working: true }, 
            () => {
                this.props.onPress(this.onWorkFinished);
            }
        );
    }

    onWorkFinished = () => {
        this.setState({ working: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                {this.state.working ? (
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                ) : (
                    this.props.children
                )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );  
    }
}
```

And then use it like a normal button with additional logic!

```js
export class NavigationScreen extends Component {

    navigate = (done) => {
        // ... Asynchronous logic goes here
        done();
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen2");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {/* ... */}
                <ButtonWorker onPress={this.navigate} />
            </Frament>
        );
    }
}
```